# C# project names in the solution file

Tags: c#, rider

I would like my Text Template (CSharp tt) to access a list of C# project names of my current solution open in Rider. Are the any kind of Rider automation model to invoke? Something like what I have for [Visual Studio](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/129342/ioc-component-registration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now (Rider 2020.1) there is no way to access project model from T4 templates. But we are working on supporting similar API to be compatible with templates written for Visual Studio.

See this issue for details:

[Add support for EnvDTE in T4 tempaltes](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-35770)